# Laravel query add up all of X and Y columns for grouped hour

Tags: php, sql, laravel

In my Laravel  project, I'm having some trouble retrieving and grouping some data. I'm trying to pull some data from relevant columns, count each value and provide a total for a grouped period of time, but in order to do the grouping, I need to first get the data, and my select isn't working quite right, what am I missing?

Query

```php
UptimeChecks::where('user_id', 1)
            ->where('monitor_id', 1)
            ->where('checked_at', '>=', '2021-05-01 15:19:00')
            ->where('checked_at', '<=', '2021-05-01 17:19:00')
            ->orderBy('checked_at', 'asc')
            ->select('event', 'checked_at')
            ->get();
```

The data I get back with the above looks like:

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3447
     all: [
       App\Models\UptimeChecks {#3446
         event: "down",
         checked_at: "2021-05-01 15:37:23",
       },
       App\Models\UptimeChecks {#3445
         event: "down",
         checked_at: "2021-05-01 15:38:10",
       },
       App\Models\UptimeChecks {#3444
         event: "down",
         checked_at: "2021-05-01 15:44:07",
       },
       App\Models\UptimeChecks {#3443
         event: "up",
         checked_at: "2021-05-01 15:45:23",
       },
       App\Models\UptimeChecks {#3442
         event: "down",
         checked_at: "2021-05-01 16:05:07",
       },
       App\Models\UptimeChecks {#3441
         event: "up",
         checked_at: "2021-05-01 16:07:07",
       },
     ],
   }
```

I'm looking to get a count of all of the "down" events for a grouped hour, and a count for "up" events for the same hour, so expect something like the following to be returned:

```
{
  "2021-05-01 15:00:00": {
    down_events: 3,
    up_events: 1
  },
  "2021-05-01 16:00:00": {
    down_events: 1,
    up_events: 1
  }
}
```

Not quite sure how my query can do that?

Comment: you can group by date but date must be in one format like Y-m-d or Y-m-d h:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the collection methods `groupBy()` and `map()` after your query.

```php
UptimeChecks::...->get()
                 ->groupBy(fn($item) => $item->checked_at->format('Y-m-d H:00:00'))
                 ->map(fn($item) => [
                     'down_events' => $item->where('event', 'down')->count(),
                     'up_events' => $item->where('event', 'up')->count(),
                 ]);
```

If you don't have access to shorthand closures (php 7.4 and above)

```php
UptimeChecks::...->get()
                 ->groupBy(function ($item) {
                     return $item->checked_at->format('Y-m-d H:00:00');
                 })
                 ->map(function ($item) {
                     return [
                         'down_events' => $item->where('event', 'down')->count(),
                         'up_events' => $item->where('event', 'up')->count(),
                     ];
                 });
```

If checked_at is not a timestamp, either add it to your `$cast` property in your model.

```php
class UptimeChecks extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'checked_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Or wrap the `$item->checked_at` in a `Carbon::parse()` call.

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
groupBy(fn($item) => Carbon::parse($item->checked_at)->format('Y-m-d H:00:00'))
```

Comment: Gives me an error: `Call to a member function format() on string`

Comment: either you wrap your checked_at with Carbon::parse or checked_at should be in $casts property under your Model

Comment: I thought checked_at was a timestamp. As @PsyLogic stated, either add it to your $cast property or wrap them in Carbon::parse. I'll edit the answer to add this.

Answer (score 0):

I think for big data it is easy to use RawSQL

```
return UptimeChecks::
        selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN event= 'down' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS down_events, ".
                    "SUM(CASE WHEN event= 'up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS up_events, DATE_FORMAT('checked_at', '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as checkedDate ")
        ->groupByRaw('checkedDate')
        ->get();
```

you can use selectRaw multiple time just to clean your Code

```
return UptimeChecks::
  selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN event= 'down' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS down_events")
 ->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN event= 'up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS up_events")
 ->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT('checked_at', '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as checkedDate")
 ->groupByRaw('checkedDate')
 ->get();
```